# ACF Custom Field WP_Query, but need to get all posts, if field doesn't exist

Tags: query-posts, advanced-custom-fields, meta-query

I have a custom ACF field set on all posts, called `event_date`, I would like to grab all posts within a given `category`, but have posts that have `event_date` defined put first in DESC order of `event_date`.  The `args` I'm using for `query_posts` are as follows:

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'cat' => $category_id,
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'event_date',
            'value' => date("Ymd", time()),
            'compare' => $type == 'upcoming' ? '>=' : '<'
        )
    ),
    'orderby' => 'meta_value',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'meta_key' => 'event_date'
);
```

But the problem I'm facing is that the ACF field was created for post types, after all posts have been created, so many of these posts do not have `event_date` even defined for the meta_key (which omits these posts from the query automatically when using `query_posts($args)`.  There are too many posts to go through all posts and save them all manually, would take forever.

Basically, if the `meta_key` for any post does not have `event_date` than I need to use the `date` of the actual post itself (when it was published) to order by.  I need all posts with `event_date` shown first in DESC order of `event_date`, than all posts that don't have `event_date` defined, need to be shown after that using the published date of the post in DESC order.  How can I do this?  Preferably, all in 1 `query_posts` call?

Thanks :)

Comment: Never use `query_posts`, it breaks the main query objects and a huge amount of other stuff that relies on the main query object

Comment: @PieterGoosen what should I use to accomplish this?  `$wpdb->get_results("SELECT STATEMENT, etc. etc.", ARRAY_A);`

Comment: Why not run a script which sets the custom field for you, and then after that, you can do one `WP_Query` and query all posts normally (*if this is not the main query, in which case you should be using `pre_get_posts`*)

Comment: This is not using the main query object.  This is being used on a regular page to pull in all posts associated with a given category, order by custom field, than if custom field does not exist, order by published date.  Not sure if using `pre_get_posts` will help here, as it might interfere with main wp query (tho not entirely sure of this).  Can you please provide example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get both with an `OR` `meta_query` that also checks if the key does not exist:

```
'meta_query' => array(
    'relation' => 'OR',
    array(
        'key' => 'event_date',
        'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS',
    ),
    array(
        'key' => 'event_date',
        'value' => date("Ymd", time()),
        'compare' => '>',
    ),
),
'orderby' => array(
    'meta_value_num' => 'DESC',
    'date' => 'ASC',
),
```

Comment: Yes, I was looking at this, but how would I use the following `'orderby' => 'meta_value',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'meta_key' => 'event_date'` or is this not needed anymore?

Comment: You still need those for the order. Note that you can also set multiple orderby fields, see the [examples on `WP_Query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters).

Comment: Yes, I see, however, `'meta_key' => 'event_date'`, `meta_key` must be present if `orderby` has `meta_value` in it, and `meta_key` can not be an array.  How to do this?

Comment: It works without `meta_key`, just set `orderby`. see edit above for parameters I tested with.

Comment: Syntax is a bit off, but your code works, thanks a ton!  Very helpful!

Comment: *some assembly required.

Answer (score 0):

The most probable route I will take with this is to run a script that would add the desired custom field to the posts which does not have the custom field assigned.

You can try the following: (***NOTE:*** This is untested)

```
add_action( 'wp', function ()
{
    $args = [
        'post_type'        => 'post', // Set according to needs
        'posts_per_page'   => -1, // Set to execute smaller chucks per page load if necessary
        'suppress_filters' => true,
        'fields'           => 'ids',
        'meta_query'       => [
            [
                'key'      => 'event_date',
                'compare'  => 'NOT EXISTS'
            ]
        ]
    ];
    $q = get_posts( $args );
    foreach ( $q as $post_id ) {
        add_post_meta( 
            $post_id, // Post ID
            'event_date', // Custom field name
            get_the_date( 'Ymd', $post_id )
        );  
     }
});
```

You can run this by simply loading any page after which you can remove it. If you set smaller chuncks, like `posts_per_page=100`, you will refresh the page until all posts are done. Note that this is quite an expensive resource intensve script which might lead to a time out fatal error, so if you have a huge amount of posts you can run smaller amount of posts per page load.

After this you can run your query as normal as per question. Just a tip though, never ever use `query_posts`, use `WP_Query` to run your custom query (*or use `get_posts` alternatively*)